# jquery how to post to php, synchronztion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I want post to php, when id EmpAgree1,and then it's post variable EmpAgree=1; when id EmpAgree2,and then it's post variable EmpAgree=2, etc. But it is just read the last value of i, why? And how to resolve it?

Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i;
    for(i=1; i <= <?php echo sizeof($id) ?> ; i++) {
        $("#EmpAgree"+i).click(function() {
            $.post("information_receiving.php", {
            EmpAgree : i
            });

            document.location.href="information_receiving.php";
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use the the last value of **i** which is (**sizeof($id)**) in this case.
To resolve it, try to store the number in the #EmpAgree elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i;
for( i=1; i <= <?php echo sizeof($id) ?> ; i++){
 $("#EmpAgree"+i).data('nbr', i).click(function(){
     $.post("information_receiving.php",{
         EmpAgree : $(this).data('nbr')
});
   document.location.href="information_receiving.php";
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bind click event inside for loop, You can create click event for element which has name like EmpAgree using `$( "input[name^='EmpAgree']" )`

Try:

```js
$( "input[name^='EmpAgree']" ).click(function(){
     var name = $(this).attr("name"); // get name
     var  i = name.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ); // extract integer from name
     console.log(i)
     $.post("information_receiving.php",{
         EmpAgree :  i // send i 
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="EmpAgree1" value = "EmpAgree1" /> 
<input type="button" name="EmpAgree2" value = "EmpAgree2" /> 
<input type="button" name="EmpAgree3" value = "EmpAgree3" /> 
<input type="button" name="EmpAgree4" value = "EmpAgree4" />
```

Comment: It's work! but, It's too difficult to me to understanding >< I'm just use php for half year. Can u give some info about that for me? thx

Comment: when you have multiple element in html and you want to add click event for that, you do not need to bind different click event , you can just create one click event for all element with similar class and similar name

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from the fact that the function invokes the variable rather than its value.

It could be solved by adding some attribute.
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var i;
for( i=1; i <= <?php echo sizeof($id) ?> ; i++){
$("#EmpAgree"+i).click(function(){
    $.post("information_receiving.php",{
          EmpAgree : $(this).attr("data");
    });
    document.location.href="information_receiving.php";
}).attr("data",i);
}});
```

End more elegant and complicated solution ,using the array of functions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var i;
            var funcs = [];
            function eventfunc(z) {
                return function () {
                    $.post("information_receiving.php", {
                        EmpAgree: z;
                    });
                    document.location.href = "information_receiving.php";
                };
            }
            for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                funcs[i] = eventfunc(i);
                $("#EmpAgree" + i).click(funcs[i]);
            }
        });
```